# Odoo 13 android mobile application certificate issue

Tags: android, certificate, odoo, odoo-13

I am facing the below issue while login using the android application. but, in ios application and through web browser it is working fine and certificates are valid. Anyone have an idea about this issue.

> Your server's certificate is not trusted. connection not posible
> [image]

Thanks.

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: We had such a problem, too, and the solution was combining certificates like in [this article](https://www.thesslstore.com/knowledgebase/ssl-support/combining-multiple-intermediate-certificates/).

Comment: @CZoellner In All the versions i think. i have tested with android 11 and 10.